# Show/Hide Div when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Greeting first time poster longtime reader...
    I have looked high and low and yet to find what i am wanting to do.

with in my site there is going to be building layouts "Large" over 100 rooms.
I want to be able to click on the rooms and on the right side of the page pull up info about that room. 
I want the info to be "hidden Div"
thank you all advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="screen.css" type="text/css" media="all">

</head>
<body>
<div id="building">
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Sample_Floorplan.jpg"  alt="" usemap="#map">

<map id="map" name="map">
<area class="link" shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="137,54,242,161" href="#one" target="" />
<area class="link" shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="138,182,232,256" href="#two" target="" />
<area class="link" shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="53,313,170,339" href="#three" target="" />
</map>
</div>
<div  id="menu">

<div class="tab" id="one">
This is One 

</div>
<div class="tab" id="two">
This is two 

</div>
<div class="tab" id="three">
This is three

</div>





</div>

</body>
</html>
```

here is my css

```
  html { 
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
}

body {
background-color: #e1ddd9;
font-size: 12px;
font-family: Verdana, Arial, SunSans-Regular, Sans-Serif;
color:#564b47;  
padding:0px 20px;
margin:0px;
}

#building {
float: left;
width: 75%;
background-color: #fff;
margin:0px 0px 50px 0px;
overflow: auto;
} 
 #menu {
float: left;
width: 25%;
background-color: #ff99CC;
overflow: auto;

}
```

Comment: look into jQuery's .hide() and .show()

Comment: or jQuery's .toggle()

Comment: thanks i will reseach that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution:

**1)** Delete the `href="#one` and add this HTML code to the `area` tags:

```
data-val="one"
```

and replace "one" with the ID to the div you want to show at that moment.

**2)** Add this jQuery-code:

```
$(".link").click(function() {
    var which = $(this).data('val');
    $(".tab").hide();
    $('#'+which).show();
});
```

See the code implemented on your current code in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3j8tq/).

Answer (score 0):

1. bind a click event to the link class. (`$('.link').on('click', function (e) { .... }`
2. prevent default on the click `e.preventDefault();`
3. hide visible tags. `$('.tab').hide();`
4. show details of clicked link. `$(INSERT SELECTOR HERE).show();`

here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G8jK2/1/).

Answer (score 0):

It's simple:

```
div
{display: none;}
```

When link is clicked, write `.show()` in jQuery.
When other links are clicked, write `.hide()` in jQuery.